# MathJax commands are undefined

Tags: wordpress, mathjax

I have been trying to use MathJax through HTML to convert some of my Latex notes to my WordPress website. 
The basic math works totally fine. I have some problems with some of the commands tho. They show as undefined:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o38f6.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRjNE.png)

I'm using this script I found on the MathJax website:

[HTML Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nj5U.png)

Thank you very much for taking your time to help me :)

Here is a live link to the website: økonominoter.dk - it's a danish website

Comment: Please post a link to a live page exhibiting the problem. Very likely you're using the wrong configuration (AsciiMath instead of LaTeX).

Comment: Here is a live page: økonominoter.dk. It's a danish side though.

Comment: Ok, you've set it up correctly. You're just using unsupported macros. The list of default macros is at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands. The same page explains how to define custom macros.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @PeterKrautzberger. But it's a supported macro, I see them on the list, which confuses me? :)

Comment: Do you have a link that shows a problem? økonominoter.dk is working fine for me.

Comment: Everything is working now, I figured it out :)!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. If there was an issue with MathJax, I'd still like to hear more about it.

Comment: There wasn't an issue with MathJax I just needed to use another script and edit some stuff in the configuration. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know and glad to see you got it to work.